# Apache gives me 403 Access Forbidden when DocumentRoot points to two different drives

Tags: windows, apache, virtualhost, http-status-code-403

I am getting an 403 access forbidden when attempting to open a page under a vhost where the document root is sitting on a different drive than where apache is sitting. I installed using the apachefriends release. This is my httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1
```

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
  ServerName foo.localhost
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/foo/public"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
  ServerName bar.localhost
  DocumentRoot "F:/bar/public"
</VirtualHost>

When opening bar.localhost in my browser, Apache is giving me 403 Access Forbidden. I tried setting lots of different access rights, even full rights to everyone, but nothing I tried helped.

Edit: Thanks! For future reference, add 'Options indexes' within to show directory indexes.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You did not need

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Require all granted
```

the only thing what you need is...

```
Require all granted
```

...inside the directory section.

See Apache 2.4 upgrading side:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html

Comment: +1 This should be the correct answer. saved me a lot of headache.

Comment: Great. You helped me very much.

Comment: In my case I still need `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews`

Comment: Just to clarify, this is in response to @cloudwhale's answer, yes? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12519708/1493346)

Comment: I am using xampp in Windows server 2012, 'require all granted' written but still same issue.

Comment: I was experiencing the same problem. I have an external hard drive in my Windows 10 system and that has the path F. While I tried to create a virtualhost with DocumentRoot "F:/htdocs", I was getting same error. This solution solve my problem.

Answer (score 50):

Somewhere, you need to tell Apache that people are allowed to see contents of this directory.

```
<Directory "F:/bar/public">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
    # Any other directory-specific stuff
</Directory>
```

[More info](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/core.html#directory)

Comment: For me, this file I had to modify was C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\conf\httpd.conf

Comment: @Moss - um, yes it does. If you're having difficulty then it is likely there is another problem - perhaps your configuration isn't being read or NTFS permissions are preventing Apache reading it. Perhaps its wise to post your own question if things still don't work for you...?

Comment: Yeah, I did post my own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859271/wampserver-403-on-named-virtual-hosts-outside-of-www. I set permissions to Full Control for Authenticated Users, SYSTEM, Administrators, on every folder from the site up to the drive. What else can be done?

Answer (score 28):

For **Apache 2.4.2**: I was getting *403: Forbidden* continuously when I was trying to access WAMP on my Windows 7 desktop from my iPhone on WiFi. On one [blog](http://dabase.com/blog/AH01630:_client_denied_by_server_configuration/), I found the solution - add **Require all granted** after *Allow all* in the *<Directory>* section. So this is how my *<Directory>* section looks like inside <VirtualHost>

```
<Directory "C:/wamp/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: (y) great! Add into vhosts.conf file

Comment: Apache 2.4 + Windows 10 + XAMPP was giving me the same error (403 forbidden). Most of the answers give "Require all granted" & that was not working. Adding "Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews Includes ExecCG" worked ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it with removing below code from

**C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf** file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
 </VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

And added

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

And it has worked like charm

Answer (score 0):

Solved 403: Forbidden when visiting localhost. Using ports 80,443,3308 (the later to handle conflict with MySQL Server installation) 
Windows 10, XAMPP 7.4.1, Apache 2.4.x My web files are in a separate folder.

httpd.conf - look for these lines and set it up where you have your files, mine is web folder.

```
DocumentRoot "C:/web"
<Directory "C:/web">
```

Changed these 2 lines.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost.com
 DocumentRoot "C:/web/project1"
 ServerName project1.localhost
 <Directory "C:/web/project1">
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

to this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost.com
 DocumentRoot "C:/web/project1"
 ServerName project1.localhost
 <Directory "C:/web/project1">
  Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Add your details in your hosts file
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 project1.localhost
```

Stop start XAMPP, and click Apache admin (or localhost) and the wonderful XAMPP dashboard now displays! And visit your project at project1.localhost