# permission for virtual host outside www directory

Tags: apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I am having trouble getting virtual hosts to work in apache 2.2.22 on linux (and windows!). I can get vhosts working within the www/html folder, but I am unable to get it working if the website folders are elsewhere. The permissions I was using in the httpd.conf file are:

```
<Directory "/path/to/my/websites">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride all
  Order Deny,Allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wampserver 403 on named virtual hosts outside of /www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859271/wampserver-403-on-named-virtual-hosts-outside-of-www)