# Apache Windows Static Files Forbidden 403

Tags: apache

The Images are in the folder "D:/images/1_Men_Boots".

```
Alias /teja/ D:/images/1_Men_Boots
<Directory D:/images/1_Men_Boots>   
    AllowOverride None  
    Order allow,deny  
    Allow from all  
</Directory>
```

The above is the apache configuration. When i call "http://127.0.0.1/teja/1.jpeg" ***i am getting 403 forbidden***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache gives me 403 Access Forbidden when DocumentRoot points to two different drives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89118/apache-gives-me-403-access-forbidden-when-documentroot-points-to-two-different-d)

Comment: @juzraai.... Issue didnt resolved with the above solution...same error

Comment: Which Apache and Windows versions are you using? It seems solution may differ between Apache versions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204902/wamp-403-forbidden-message-on-windows-7

Comment: @juzraai.....windows server 2012 and apache 2.4....Not using wamp only apache